# vbs run command no output

Tags: vbscript

Okay I created a small script to call "net file" and pump the output to a file.   There are no spaces in the filenames, and everything seems okay when I run it interactively.  So I run the following and I get no results and no errors:

```
set oWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
owshell.run "net file > C:\openfiles.txt"
Set owShell = nothing
```

Now if modify this just slightly to show execute the same command (and keep my command window open) it works just as expected (except it keeps the cmd window open which I can't have)

```
set oWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
owshell.run "%comspec% /k net file > C:\openfiles.txt"
Set owShell = nothing
```

It must be something obvious that I'm just missing.  I only touch vbs once in a blue moon so it isn't something that I'm that used to using.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understood: what's the matter? No output?

Answer (score 2):

You need a shell (i.e. %comspec%) to get shell features like redirection; the persisten window is what you asked for: the /k lets the shell  stay open (try /c instead) and you should use the second and third parameter of the .Run method to get a hidden window (and possibly wait for the process before you zap the owShell).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Run](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html). Changing

```
owshell.run "%comspec% /k net file > C:\openfiles.txt"
```

to

```
owshell.run "%comspec% /c net file > C:\openfiles.txt", 0, FALSE
```

This will hide the cmd and carry on with the rest of the script... If you want to wait for the command to finish, change `FALSE` to `TRUE`.

Also keep in mind that some machines are funny about letting you write files directly to C:\. Possibly create a test folder and write to there instead!