# How to get Plink command response in a vbscript variable?

Tags: unix, vbscript, plink

I am checking for the number of files I have in a Unix Directory, and I am trying to get that number in a VBScript variable.

My code:

```
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "C:\PLINK.EXE -ssh user@host -pw abc find /my/files -name '*333*' | wc -l > C:\files\res.txt"
set oShell = Nothing
```

The above code didn't write in the `.txt` file. I was thinking that i'll read the `.txt` file using vbscript and get the count.

Is there a direct way to to get the count returned from `wc -l` in a vbscript variable.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a shell (%comspec%) to get shell features like redirection (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348713/603855)). So change

```
oShell.Run "C:\PLINK.EXE -ssh user@host -pw abc find /my/files -name '*333*' | wc -l > C:\files\res.txt"
```

to

```
oShell.Run "%comspec% /c C:\PLINK.EXE -ssh user@host -pw abc find /my/files -name '*333*' | wc -l > C:\files\res.txt"
```

**after** you have checked that

```
C:\PLINK.EXE -ssh user@host -pw abc find /my/files -name '*333*' | wc -l > C:\files\res.txt
```

'works' from a console.

In case of trouble study the docs for [.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (parameters, return value) and [.Exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (Stdout/Stderr capturing) and simplify (e.g. no `| wc -l`).