# Cscript Syntax from VBS Script

Tags: vbscript, wsh

This is the code I run from commandline:

```
wscript C:\pw_decoder.vbs C:\settings.vbe >> C:\pw.vbs
```

this is working fine, but from vbs I´m only getting errors like "not enough parameters". I already tried the following:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run("wscript C:\pw_decoder.vbs C:\settings.vbe >> C:\pw.vbs")

Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run("wscript ""C:\pw_decoder.vbs C:\settings.vbe >> C:\pw.vbs"" ")

Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run("wscript ""C:\pw_decoder.vbs"" ""C:\settings.vbe"" >> ""C:\pw.vbs"" ")
```

Unfortunately I had no success until now.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you're using a script to write and execute a new script - that's rather convoluted.

Comment: You need a shell for re-direction. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30238082/603855

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks, that worked great!!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, the command "wscript C:\pw_decoder.vbs C:\settings.vbe >> C:\pw.vbs"
call wscript with 4 args (1:C:\pw_decoder.vbs     2:C:\settings.vbe      3:>>        4:C:\pw.vbs).

If you want to call a vbs from command line, you don't need to call wscript before.

By calling your vbs file directly, the command: oShell.run("C:\pw_decoder.vbs C:\settings.vbe >> C:\pw.vbs")
call pw_decode.vbs with 3 args (1:C:\settings.vbe      2:>>        3:C:\pw.vbs)

Now, what do you need as arguments in pw_decoder.vbs?